# What is Sonar Search?

Tags: sonarqube

I am upgrading an install of SonarQube from 4.5.1 to 5.2.  I wasn't part of the original install and when looking at the sonar.properties file to see what needs to be update in the new one, I see properties for "sonar.search".

What is Sonar Search?  Why would I need to uncomment/update these properties?

I haven't been able to find any good documentation on the SonarQube website on what it is and "sonar" and "search" internet searches bring up way too many unrelated results to sift through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an Elasticsearch instance used for indexing some database tables. It allows for example powerful search requests on issues. See the sidebar of page "Issues". It supports multi-criteria searches and displays valuable facets.

Default settings in sonar.properties are good enough for most of environments. JVM settings of this dedicated process could be overridden if dozens of millions of issues are stored in database.